# Why use ServletContext.setAttribute()?

Tags: servlets, setattribute

Why would we set ServletContext parameters using the `setAttribute()` method, as we can accomplish the same thing by setting parameters in `web.xml` and fetching them using `getInitParameter()`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `servletContext.setAttribute()` is dynamic which can be set and reset during runtime.

Where as `init-parameter` specified in `web.xml` is static which will not change during the lifetime of application.

**Example:**

- The database properties like database name configuration propety. It will be mostly configured as context `init-param`
- And if you want to set property value which derives based on runtime changes, like "last user logged in" or "number of failures" should be context attributes.

Comment: For Servlet 2.5, would the ServletContext.getInitParameter() return the same attribute set by ServletContext.setAttribute() ?