# How do I pass a value throughout my project and use it anywhere in the program

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, servlets

How do I pass a value throughout my  project and use it anywhere in the program. .. The value is selected before the login page...  I want to access it anytime and in any jsp or servelet in a project

Comment: Google for sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HttpSession to do the same.

Other than this you can initialize context parameters.

Follow this link for parameters approach.

[init-param and context-param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392888/init-param-and-context-param)